# Scriptaculous function to jQuery

Tags: jquery, addclass

I have a scriptaculous function that I need to change to Jquery.

```
$$("div.mydiv a").each( function(el) {
    Event.observe(el, "mouseover", function() {
        $('other').addClassName(el.className+'hover');
    });
});
$$("div.mydiv a").each( function(el) {
    Event.observe(el, "mouseout", function() {
        $('other').removeClassName(el.className+'hover');
    });
});
```

Please, does anyone has Any idea of how to do that ?

Comment: By starting to read the jQuery documentation and finding corresponding methods: http://api.jquery.com/

Comment: Why not use `.hover()` : http://api.jquery.com/hover/ ?

Comment: Or even the CSS Selector `:hover` ?

Comment: Ok guys, sorry for being so lazy (thanks) but the hover, the addclass or the remove is not the problem. My bad.
The real problem is that jquery add a space to my class.
The second is to have the element base classname like here "el.classname".

Comment: @ced: Could you be more precise please? Creating a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo would help to. Then describe the result you get (with example) and the results you want to get.

Comment: Ok Felix, thanks and done:
[http://jsfiddle.net/ced29/6VMmX/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/ced29/6VMmX/4/)
The wish is to have that result for the a hovered class:
    #theclass.alshover
with no space. als being dynamically taken because I have 40 differents class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $('div.mydiv a').hover(function(){
     $('other').addClass($(this).attr('class')+'hover') ;
},function(){
     $('other').removeClass($(this).attr('class')+'hover') ;
});
```

[more info](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

Comment: See my comment at @Chamika's answer. In addition, `$('other')` will find the element with tagname `other`, which does not exist in HTML.

Comment: I thought 'other' represents other selector (.other|#other...)

Comment: @Martin, Thank you Martin, that perfectly works. Just needed a little change in my css but that does the job. Also, an error for me caused by my forgotten non conflict mode ($ instead of $cc).
@ all those who try to give a help, thank you too guys.
@ those who closed that post without ever having answered...

Answer (score 1):

it seems like what you want is this :

http://jsfiddle.net/Qchmqs/VbPGd/

just tweak it to suit your current html

i don't know about  scriptaculous

but i feel like this is the effect you want to acheive

Comment: Err no ... `mouseover` and `click` are very different ?

Comment: i know they are differenet i said tweak it (change what you don't like the idea is the same)

Comment: Thanks Qchmqs but can you get dynamicly the element class ('cause it change for each element like "bre1, bre2, bre3" ?